# mid 2009 iPod Touch not downloading from the app store

Tags: ipod, ipod-touch, ios

Ever since iOS4.0 came out (even before I installed it) my iPod Touch no longer downloads apps from the appstore.  The appstore itself loads (slowly) but when I try to buy something, it just takes unbelievably long and then doesn't even ask me for my password 9/10 times.  I haven't tried buying a paid app because I don't want to pay for something that I don't get.

I can still buy apps from my laptop, but it's a pain.

I'm currently in Australia, but I still use the US appstore (since that's where I live).

Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: (Retagged as per http://meta.gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/29)

Answer (score 1):

Contact Apple to ask about this behavior. Apple devices are relatively difficult to break, and it could be caused by the distance between your device and its home country (and servers).

Comment: The distance argument doesn't work because the app store problems started the day iOS4 was released, but I've been in Australia for the past 2 months.  But I guess I will have to contact them.  Thanks